# Error when saving bitmap to MemoryStream a second time

Tags: c#

I've read other threads about this issue, but alas I haven't found anything to get me past this error:

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+
```

There are plenty of instances regarding this error, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I have the following code - it scales an image if the correct parameters are met:

```
/// <summary>
/// Apply scaling (if enabled) to the given image 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="imageToScale">Scale image down by x.</param>
/// <param name="watchmanData">Watchman data containing settings.</param>
/// <returns>The original image, or a scaled down one.</returns>
public static Bitmap ApplyScaling(Bitmap imageToScale, Setting watchmanData)
{
    var returnData = imageToScale;

    if (watchmanData.ActuallyScaleDown)
    {
        using (var inStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageToScale.Save(inStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

            inStream.Position = 0;

            using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                outStream.Position = 0;

                MagicImageProcessor.ProcessImage(inStream, outStream,
                    new ProcessImageSettings {Width = imageToScale.Width / watchmanData.ScaleBy});

                returnData = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(outStream);

                outStream.Close();
            }

            inStream.Close();
        }
    }

    return returnData;
}
```

This code works the first time without issue. However on the second one at the line:

```
imageToScale.Save(inStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

I get the error.

I've set the stream positions to 0, I've closed the streams once processing is complete, and yet I still get this error.

I was under the assumption that the **using** would get rid of the streams after they were finished. The image being passed in is even a different instance:

```
var window = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ImageOperations.ApplyScaling(WindowOperations.TakeScreenshot(focusWindow), watchmanSettings));
var split = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ImageOperations.ApplyScaling(lookFor, watchmanSettings));
```

(Error occurs when the second image is sent through, in this case labelled as "split")

I must be doing something wrong, as the code works the first time around, any guidance or things to check would be grand, thank you.

Comment: Isn't it somehow related itself? If you swap the calls, will the second one fail or the first one?

Comment: That you got a GDI+ error is a strong indicator that there is something up with your image you provided to the method (imageToScale), and not with the MemoryStream (which would most likely produce some form of IOException if it suffered some problem)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - You were right, I defined a nnew instance higher in the stack and it went through perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: There are two glaring bugs in this snippet, my crystal ball says that you feed the returned bitmap object back into the same method.  The storage for a Bitmap must remain accessible until you call the bitmap's Dispose() method.  Which means that the inner *using* statement as well as outStream.Close() are wrong.  It doesn't always cause an instant crash, enough data from the storage might have been buffered.  You don't have to Close() or Dispose() a memory stream, it is just memory, so the bugs are easy to fix.

Comment: Yup, `BitMap: Image` and `Image: IDisposable`, and it's stream is what it disposes upon disposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a bitmap from the `outStream`, and that's the bitmap's underlying storage...so you don't want to whack it. And, when you're `using` a resource, you don't want/need to close it yourself. To clarify:

```
/// <summary>
/// Apply scaling (if enabled) to the given image 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="imageToScale">Scale image down by x.</param>
/// <param name="watchmanData">Watchman data containing settings.</param>
/// <returns>The original image, or a scaled down one.</returns>
public static Bitmap ApplyScaling(Bitmap imageToScale, Setting watchmanData)
{
    var returnData = imageToScale;

    if (watchmanData.ActuallyScaleDown)
    {
        using (var inStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageToScale.Save(inStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

            inStream.Position = 0;  //--> not sure you need this...maybe

            var outStream = new MemoryStream();

            MagicImageProcessor.ProcessImage(inStream, outStream,
                new ProcessImageSettings {
                   Width = imageToScale.Width / watchmanData.ScaleBy});

            returnData = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(outStream);
        }
    }

    return returnData;
}
```

From [Image.FromStream Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.7.2) - note in remarks:

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

Comment: Point of the comment in code...I don't know doodly about MagicImageProcessor...maybe it's smart enough to manage the stream position itself.